# How to set the "checked" value of a React switch to a reference in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

```
  const passiveIncomeTaxable = useRef(false);

  <Modal.Body hidden={SimpleMode}>
    <Form.Check
         type="switch"
        label="Is this income taxable?"
         name="income-passive"
           id="income-passive"
          ref={passiveIncomeTaxable}
     />
  </Modal.Body>
```

Everything here seems to be working just fine, but if I change the value of the switch and log the switch value to the console, it always returns **on**, even if the switch component is set to **off**.

I need to store the value of the switch component to a reference so that I could insert it into the database.

Comment: Is FormCheck a custom component you made?  if it is are you accessing `passiveIncomeTaxable.current`?

Comment: Yes thought the same. A ref in React is a container for the actual value. You might forgot to access it by getting the field `current` of the ref

Comment: yes I use console.log(passiveIncomeTaxable.current.value) and it return "on", even if I switched the component to a "off" position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use state:

```
const [isTaxable, setIsTaxable] = useState(false);
```

```
<Form.Check
  type="switch"
  label="Is this income taxable?"
  name="income-passive"
  id="income-passive"
  checked={isTaxable}
  onChange={() => setIsTaxable(prev => !prev)}
/>
```

Or, to make it uncontrolled:

```
const passiveIncomeTaxable = useRef(false)
```

```
<Form.Check
  type="switch"
  label="Is this income taxable?"
  name="income-passive"
  id="income-passive"
  onChange={() => {
    console.log(passiveIncomeTaxable.current.checked)
  }}
  ref={passiveIncomeTaxable}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                <CFormSwitch
                    id="status"
                    name="status"
                    value={input.status}
                    checked={input.status === 'active'}
                    onChange={statusChange}
                />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).